# No data returned after SQL select * on mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to extract data from a table in Mysql. When I try to do a `select *  from table` I get no data. If I add a `where` clause then it returns data. I have more than 100k tagnames which I can't add in the filter condition. Can anyone point me why I'm seeing this kind of behaviour and how to extract data without specifying `Tagname`

The select statement after adding a where clause is as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM ahpvdb.DailyPVInst DailyPVInst_0
WHERE
(DailyPVInst_0.TagName IN ( 'UMA-PDIN33'))
AND (DailyPVInst_0.StartTime = {ts '2020-01-01 03:00:00' })
AND (DailyPVInst_0.EndTime = {ts '2025-12-31 03:00:00' })
```

My table DDL is as below:

```
    CREATE TABLE `DailyPVInst` (
  `RowNum` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique number in result set',
  `TagName` char(56) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Altacs tag name',
  `StartTime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested history start time in GMT(UTC)',
  `EndTime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested history end time in GMT(UTC)',
  `RecFrq` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Altacs tag recording frequency',
  `Value` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tag sample value',
  `TimeStamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Tag sample time',
  `QF1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tag sample quality flag 1',
  `QF2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Tag sample quality flag 2',
  PRIMARY KEY (`TagName`,`StartTime`,`EndTime`,`RecFrq`,`RowNum`)
) ENGINE=ALTACSAH DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Select * from [Table_Name] where Tagname="ABC" and starttime="2015-01-24 15:20:00" and endtime="2015-01-24 15:30:00" and RecFrq=2;' `VAROPT`='5';
```

PS: I tried using subquery as well but no luck. Subquery used is as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM ahpvdb.DailyPVInst DailyPVInst_0
WHERE
(DailyPVInst_0.TagName IN ( select distinct TagName from ahpvdb.DailyPVInst))
AND (DailyPVInst_0.StartTime = {ts '2020-01-01 03:00:00' })
AND (DailyPVInst_0.EndTime = {ts '2025-12-31 03:00:00' })
```

Comment: What is `ENGINE=ALTACSAH`? I have never heard of this, and I find nothing in a google search.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Bill Karwin `ENGINE=ALTACSAH` is custom storage engine and plugged to MySQL server

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Mysql

Comment: I remember working once with a MySQL database where queries NOT using indexes were blocked i.e. `SELECT * FROM table`. Therefore when I wanted to still select everything I had to do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 0`. I don't remember wheat was the name of that setting / option, but maybe that'll lead you to google for the right thing.

Comment: Perhaps it's a quirk of this storage engine

Comment: @Atchu, What's the message you are getting after executing select * from table?

Comment: start with only one where condition and then add one by one , i doubt there is a row for that condition

Comment: @nbk I tried with where condition and it still didn't work. Data returned only after adding 2 where conditions.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur no message. Just 0 rows rows returned

Comment: @6bytes by any chance do you remember the setting? I tried googling but couldn't find this setting.

Comment: you have to check the engine for that behaviour, it is odd, but when the engine is so programmend

Comment: Does the `COMMENT` have any meaning in this version of MySQL

Comment: Are you testing those queries directly in MySQL client or are you executing them through some code (PHP, Node, Python...). I wonder if the issue is on MySQL side or code side.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above, you said ALTACSAH is a custom storage engine, I assume implemented at your organization. MySQL allows developers to create their own storage engine as a C++ class (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html).

Hypothetically, a storage engine that does not [implement table-scan operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/implementing-basic-table-scanning.html) might return nothing when a given search is not indexed. This could be by design, or it could be the result of a code bug.

No one on Stack Overflow who doesn't work at your organization can know anything about the implementation of your custom storage engine. We have never used it, and we don't have access to its code or documentation.

If you use a bespoke storage engine, I'm afraid debugging it is up to you.